# split aspx page into sections rendered in tabs that load on demand

Tags: javascript, tabs, webforms

what is the easiest most efficient - from a performance standpoint - way to program an aspx that will have sections in it rendered as tabs and preferably to be loaded on demand?
I have a certain entity that can be edited by different groups of users, each user group being able to edit certain parts of it. I am thinking of rendering the parts accessible to a group in a tab on the page and then controlling access/load of the tabs based on user rights.
i know a couple of javascript frameworks that address this specific type of requirements do exist, however i am a novice js programmer, i never used it for anything more than handling control events and doing very basic stuff so i do not know how fast i can pick up and use one of them.

Comment: Is there a particular reason to load them on demand?  When the page is initially requested (generally in the context of `Page_Load` here) you have a user's access rights, correct?  If each "tab" on the page is something like a `PlaceHolder` then you can show/hide them according to user permissions (usually setting the server-side `.Visible` property on the controls) when initially rendering the page.  Then the users will only see what they're allowed to see.  Assuming the user's permissions don't change by the second, I see no reason to asynchronously load the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need tabs for that, have it a single page and just load/display data relevant to current user group.

One way to do this (since you're using ASP.NET) is to use MultiView control and display relevant View control for the current user group.

Comment: well depending on their rights, the user can edit one or multiple sections of the page. as to why i want to load asynchronously, it's because it's a huge page with a lot of controls in it.

Comment: Ah not one part, but multiple. In that case I suggest load individual portions of page into iframe. When user click specific "tab" - specific SRC is loaded into iframe